# keyboard hide input (position:fixed; bottom:0;) with phonegap on android

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

Tried a lot of things

```
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="false" />  
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode"    value="adjustResize" />
```

This seems to be the prefered methods however my keyboard still show on top of my input.

Should adjustResize force the app window to resize? do I need something else?

How can I stop it from hiding my element in position fixed bottom?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

Add these piece of code in `$(document).ready(function() {});` function in your html page where soft keyboard is appearing.

```
 var initialScreenSize = window.innerHeight;
 window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  if(window.innerHeight < initialScreenSize){
     $("#footer").hide();
     document.body.style.position = "fixed";
  }
  else{
     document.body.style.position = "";
     $("#footer").show();                                      
  }
 });
```

This will might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect focused textarea or input then wait a while until keyboard is shown and finally scroll the page to reach focused input. Hope this help you, cheers.

```
var container = $('body'),
        scrollTo = $('#textarea');

    setTimeout((function() {
        container.animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
        });
    }), 500);
```